# How to merge only on rows where there is no value in the rows of a certain column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have the following dataframe df1,

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker ....................
0   Apple Inc.       US      AAPL
1   Microsoft        US
2   Sony             US
3   DBS              SG      D05
4   Razer            HK      0700
5   General Electric US      GE
```

Then I have a list of all the company names with just their tickers tickerdf,

```
    CompanyName      Ticker 
0   Apple Inc.       AAPL
1   Microsoft        MSFT
2   Sony             SNE     
3   DBS              D05.SI
4   Razer            0700.HK
5   General Electric GE
```

If I wanted to merge, on the company name I would do,

```
mergeddf = pd.merge(df1,tickerdf,on=['CompanyName'], how='left')
```

But if I did that I would end up with all the Ticker values from tickerdf1 like this

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker ....................
0   Apple Inc.       US      AAPL
1   Microsoft        US      MSFT
2   Sony             US      SNE
3   DBS              SG      D05.SI
4   Razer            HK      0700.HK
5   General Electric US      GE
```

But, I want it to retain the values from the df1, basically only merge on the rows where there is no data on the ticker column, the output should look like this.

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker ....................
0   Apple Inc.       US      AAPL
1   Microsoft        US      MSFT
2   Sony             US      SNE
3   DBS              SG      D05
4   Razer            HK      0700
5   General Electric US      GE
```

Is it possible to only merge data on rows where the Ticker column is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `fillna`:

```
# Ticker by company
s = df2.set_index('CompanyName')['Ticker']

df['Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].fillna(df['CompanyName'].map(s) )
```

Comment: what are you doing with the set_index command? you combine the company name and ticker into a list ?

Comment: `set_index` makes `CompanyName` an index so as `pandas` can look up `Ticker` by the `CompanyName`. Then I use `map` to turn the `CompanyName` in `df` into ticker indicated in `df2`.

Comment: as in, so df2 becomes a series?

Comment: Close, but it's still a dataframe, albeit with one column. One-column dataframe and series are still of different classes.

Comment: hey what do I do if I have multiple "CompanyNames", for example Apple Inc in usa and Apple Inc in Mexico. They have different tickers, because they're listed in different countries, I want all the tickers. is that possible?